# Type annotations for class fields

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to annotate class fields, but mypy (0.670) fails to raise an issue in the code below:

```
class X(object):
    x: int
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "a"

x = X()
```

Is there a way to perform type checks on class fields using mypy? If not, is there a way to easily do it at run-time?

Comment: Don't have a Python3 environment to test atm, but it looks like [this](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code) part of the docs may be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a simple runtime check using the `typeguard` module.

```
import typing
import typeguard

def check_class_hints(obj):
    hints = typing.get_type_hints(obj.__class__)
    for (name, hint_ty) in hints.items():
        val = getattr(obj, name)
        typeguard.check_type(name, val, hint_ty)

class X(object):
    x: int
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "a"

x = X()
check_class_hints(x)
```